# Way to free memory in recursive functions?

Tags: php

This recursive function uses over 1.4 MB of RAM, and it's not freed. All it returns is a single int.  How can I free up much more memory?

```
function bottomUpTree($item, $depth)
{
   if ($depth)
   {
      --$depth;
      $newItem = $item << 1;
      return array(
         bottomUpTree($newItem - 1, $depth),
         bottomUpTree($newItem, $depth),
         $item
      );
   }
   unset($depth);
   unset($newItem);
   return array(NULL, NULL, $item);
}

bottomUpTree(0, 7);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursive functions will always suck up memory. Each call will use up a bit more until you reach the bottom and start returning. This is unavoidable. Doing `unset()` on the function's parameters won't help you... they've already taken up space on the call stack and can't be removed until the function returns.

One option would be to switch over to an iterative function, but that's harder to do with a tree-structure.

But most of all, what does this function actually accomplish? You're returning arrays, but not assigning them anywhere in the calling level, so you're creating a ton of arrays only to throw them away again immediately.

Comment: It's the official PHP benchmark script from https://alioth.debian.org/  I wanted to know why it required hundreds of MBs of RAM.

Comment: Odd, when I run it here I get a peak usage of 840,592 bytes via command line and 835,832 bytes via Apache (stock PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.2 from Ubuntu 10.04LTS)

Comment: Yeah you dont have it in a major for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

A few tricks to getting the php compiler to release memory are to do the following:

1. Extract the memory intensive pieces of your recursive function to it's own function/method. PHP won't release memory until the function finishes/exits/returns.
2. Before returning in your extracted function/method set variables to NULL.
3. Call gc_collect_cycles() after you call the memory intensive function.